# How can I use a Lua module in MediaWiki to display graphs

Tags: lua, mediawiki

I currently have a Lua module that does some manipulation on data it is passed then I would like it to display a graph on an article.

I am having trouble getting the graph displaying properly however I have tried a couple of approaches thus far:

> Output in the form of {{Graph:Chart|variablesHere}} using the graph template as is recommended on the extension page, which works fine usually. The problem with this approach is that (I assume) because it comes from a module the text isn't actually processed by MediaWiki and therefore display plaintext.
>
> Using require('Module:Graph') and and printing the output to the page, however it does not correctly make a graph either as it isn't properly formatted and I haven't been able to understand how to convert it like Template:Graph:Chart does

Just looking for any suggestions on where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `frame:preprocess(string_containing_templates)` to expand a string that contains templates such as [Template:Graph:Chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Graph:Chart).

If you want to avoid preprocessing, you could call the `chart` function of [Module:Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module:Graph), but it is complicated to get the same result as expanding Template:Graph:Chart because you have to translate the contents of Template:Chart:Graph to Lua. To generate the same content as `frame:preprocess("{{Graph:Chart|width=100|height=100|x=1|y=1}}")`, you would do:

```
 frame:extensionTag("templatestyles", nil, { src = "Graph:Chart/styles.css" })
  .. frame:extensionTag (
    "graph",
    require("Module:Graph").chart { args = { width = '100', height = '100', x = '1', y = '1' } }
  )
```

Here `frame` must be a frame object. Not very pretty, and if any changes are made to the template, they won't be reflected in your module code. So it is probably best to just preprocess the template.